# Programming books for high school students

Tags: computer-science

Is there any basic books that talks about what the memory is, storage, or any like science inside the computer? I am a starter at programming, but I want to know how the computers work and function. Is there a book that connect programming and computer basics? And what do you guys read when you are beginners at programming? Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Programming for the Absolute Beginner:-
Programming for the Absolute Beginner provides a gentle learning curve in programming for anyone who wants to develop fundamental programming skills and create computer programs.

Comment: Please add the author to the title to help the OP in finding it, if you find the time. I for one do not know the book / document. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but which one?

Comment: And does the book include the thing like structure of the cup or the connection between it and programming?